# Deploying Expressjs + Nextjs application on Vercel

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, vercel

I'm currently trying to deploy my express + nextjs app on vercel. They are linked like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const compression = require('compression');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const io = require('socket.io');
const Next = require('next');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const connectDB = require('./services/mongo');
const SettingsStream = require('./listeners/settings');
const blogRouter = require('./api/blog');
const settingsRouter = require('./api/settings');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const fw = Next({ dev });
const handle = fw.getRequestHandler();

fw.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const app = express();
    app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'public/favicon.ico')));

    const server = http.createServer(app);

    const sio = io.listen(server);

    const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 5000;

    sio.on('connection', (client) => {
      SettingsStream(client);
    });
    //
    const shouldCompress = (req, res) => {
      if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
        return false;
      }

      return compression.filter(req, res);
    };
    //
    dotenv.config();
    //
    connectDB();
    //
    app.use(compression({ shouldCompress }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use(cors());
    //
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyparser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    //
    // // Use routes
    app.use('/api/blog', blogRouter);
    app.use('/api/settings', settingsRouter);
    //
    if (dev) {
      app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`App is runnign in port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })

  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

Then in my package.json I have a script for serving it to Vercel:

`"vercel-build": " next build && NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js",`

Vercel runs the first part and builds the next app, but it gets stuck in a loop when the second part  runs. How do you properly serve such an app to Vercel?

Comment: Unless changed in the last 3 months, Vercel doesn't support a server: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4588#discussioncomment-24490

Answer (score 3):

I hope this solve your problem. Create a now.json / vercel.json

```
{
"version": 2,
"name": "App name",
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "api/**/*.js",
        "use": "@now/node",
        "config": {
            "maxLambdaSize": "50mb"
        }
    },
    {
        "src": "package.json",
        "use": "@now/next"
    }
  ]
}
```

As far as I know node app suggested to place in api folder. Socket is not supported by vercel, [Link](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4536)  .I am very new in this platform so please share your findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

vercel v2 api support only serverless functions, take a look at this [sample code](https://vercel.com/guides/migrate-to-vercel?query=expressjss#bonus:-dynamic-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the vercel serverless `functions` approach, or you set it up the old way, with a `vercel.json` like:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to ensure all the dependencies, like the `node_modules`, are uploaded to vercel

Answer (score 0):

To Deploy node.js on Vercel you need to install "now" first. So, here are the steps:

1- Run npm install now@latest to install the CLI
2- Create a "now.json" document on the root of the project
3- copy and paste the bell

Example of now.json file:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{
    "src": "./server.js",
    "use": "@now/node-server"
  }],
  "routes": [{"handle": "filesystem"},
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

The "server.js" is the entry point of your server please be sure you write the right filename there.

- If it still falling because the server port is in use you will need to change the server port to 80.

I hope I could help you with the deployment of your app.

Cheers!