# How to deploy ExpressJS Node-application to Vercel. Getting 404: NOT_FOUND error

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I can find [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435246/error-while-deploying-node-js-application-to-vercel), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741040/deploying-expressjs-nextjs-application-on-vercel), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311465/how-to-deploy-node-server-to-vercel), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979801/deploy-node-api-to-vercel) posts that appear to have the same problem as me, but none of them has an answer that works (nor is accepted). And the questions are either inaccurate or lacking information. So here goes (again):

I'm working on an ExpressJS, TypeScript and Node-application, started from this template: [TypeScript-Express-Starter](https://github.com/ljlm0402/typescript-express-starter). I'm trying to deploy it to Vercel, but I keep getting a 404-error:

[image: Vercel 404: NOT_FOUND]

Link in image: "[Click here to learn more about this error](https://vercel.com/docs/errors/platform-error-codes#not_found)".

I assume these are the right Vercel-settings:

- **Build command:** `npm run build`
- **Output Directory:** `dist`
- **Install command:** `npm install`

I have it running locally via Nodemon and that works. See the [nodemon.json](https://github.com/ljlm0402/typescript-express-starter/blob/master/lib/mongoose/nodemon.json) for more info.

**Overarching question:** How do I get this Node-application (that runs locally) to run on Vercel?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Get some Node-application to run on Vercel

I found this medium-article: [How to Deploy Node Express API to Vercel Serverless Functions](https://jonathans199.medium.com/deploy-node-js-express-api-to-vercel-dbf4461795a5), that deploys a skinny Node-application to Vercel. I tried following those steps, by adding those files to my existing project.

**And that worked!!**

With those files, it worked! I could now see this:

[image: API is working]

on my temporary Vercel-URL: https://projectname-c3ddpx8f7-mysecretgithubhandle.vercel.app/

**Things to note:**

- The [vercel.json](https://gist.github.com/jonathans199/537a01e85648c31132cd3d96813ab081#file-vercel-json)-file points the routes from *the root* (and not `dist`) to the `index.js`-file in the root. And my Vercel-build-settings (listed higher up) was still the same. Weird!
- The [index.js-file](https://gist.github.com/jonathans199/537a01e85648c31132cd3d96813ab081#file-index-js) is located in the root as well and not in a compiled directory.

I was thinking, if I simply needed to move *my compiled project* out of `dist` and into the root? But that seemed so silly that I didn't even try that. Since that also means committing compiled files.

### Solution attempt 2: Modify `vercel.json`-file

Since **Solution Attempt 1** got something showing, then I tried modifying `vercel.json` to this:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/server.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

But then I'm back at the 404.

### Solution attempt 3: Is this ExpressJS and Vercel incompatible?

In solution attempt 1, in the index.js-file, the
`app.listen(PORT, () => {`...-line and the
`app.get('/', (req, res) => {`...-line is in the same file.

Is this something that makes this Node-ExpressJS-application miraculously climb through the hole of the needle this serverless architecture and therefore work for a tiny example like this?
But bigger setups with ExpressJS doesn't work with it? Hmmm...

### Other thoughts

- **SSH:** I considered trying to SSH onto the server and play with it there. But since it's a serverless architecture, this isn't possible.
- **Reason to 404:** How do I figure out where this 404-error comes from? Can I catch that in my ExpressJS as a step to debug it? Maybe with something like: `app.on('error', (error) => console.error('Server error', error));`
- **Unable to choose `Node` in frameworks:** It confuses me, that I can't choose `Node` from the list of frameworks, when creating a new project. Another hint towards that Vercel and Node might not go well hand in hand. But if this is the case, why does the simple example from Solution Attempt 1 then work?! Hmm!!
- **Variations of `vercel.json`:** I've tried virtually all combinations of changes in my `vercel.json`-file, but without luck.
- **Discouraging `routes` and `builds`:** When reading Vercel's documentation about [routes](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration#routes) and [builds](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration#builds), then both sections starts with discouraging using it. Another hint towards incompatibility.

### Update - My advice

If you, like me, tried to do this and wonder: 'Can I do this'? Then my advice would be: **Don't!!**. I've tried this for a good long time, it feels like there is lacking info and an community around Vercel and NodeJS (ExpressJS at least). It's an uphill battle. I ended up just going another way in the end (deploying the app to my own little VPS).

Comment: Ahh but at least were you able to run in on vercel or you just get enough of it?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you have luck @Zeth? I deployed my api in railway.app and works perfectly but in vercel I can't. I created issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509164/vercel-deployment-issue-404-not-found and also in Vercel discussions https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/10853

Comment: @ZeR0ByTe - Nope, I never got it to work. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.
My online demo: https://vercel-express-online-demo.vercel.app.
Github: https://github.com/zhouzhonghao/vercel-express-online-demo.

1. create a express project.

```bash
# create ejs express project
npm install -g express-generator
# name is your ejs express project name such as vercel-express-online-demo
express -e [name]
```

> note the default jade express will crash in vercel so we need ejs express.

2. add an index.js file as a serverless function entry under project root folder.

```js
// index.js
require("./bin/www");
```

3. add a vercel.json config file.

```json
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

4. deploy project in vercel use default "Other" config.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue, I guess the problem is the building process and typescript needs extra setting on Vercel. My current workaround is only using VanillaJS.

I made a minimal repo using Express on Vercel and it is receiving 200 in production environment. You can customized it by the way you want it to be bundled (customized build commands or use TypeScript version).

https://github.com/The-Poe/expressVercelMinimal

[image]

Comment: Tip: unless there is something about a console contents that can only be captured an an image, please capture it as text, and use a code block. Images of text don't work with clipboards, screen-readers, and search engine robots.

Comment: Tip: is this post an answer or an adjacent question? If it is the latter, please delete it and ask a new question. The answer section is strictly for answers; folks who can answer questions won't look here.

Comment: thx, I updated it as only left the answer part.

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you show a key part of the solution in the answer, e.g. with a piece of code? That way, if the link breaks, the answer is still useful.

Comment: I add a picture to demo the folder structure.
Sorry I don't know the exact reason why it always returns 404 when publishing nodejs repo to Vercel. I am guessing it's the building process or typescript needed extra setting on vercel.

As I am only using it for me side project, I don't plan to spend so much time here. I can only share my workaround.

Answer (score -2):

### [Standalone Express](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#standalone-express)

To deploy a standalone Express app on Vercel you need to create an `index.js` file and add it to a `/api` folder.

```
const app = require('express')();
const { v4 } = require('uuid');

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  const path = `/api/item/${v4()}`;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-max-age=1, stale-while-revalidate');
  res.end(`Hello! Go to item: <a href="${path}">${path}</a>`);
});

app.get('/api/item/:slug', (req, res) => {
  const { slug } = req.params;
  res.end(`Item: ${slug}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Next you would need to add a rewrite in you `vercel.json` file at the root of your project.

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

### [Adding a Public Directory](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#adding-a-public-directory)

You can serve static content by adding a `/public` folder to the root of your project.

**Because you're using TypeScript, it's important to ensure that your TypeScript code is properly compiled and the output is in the expected location.**

For more information on this topic, see this [guide](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel) on the Vercel website.