# Vercel Deployment Issue: '404 Not Found'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vercel

I can deploy my api on vercel but I have problems. Always I receive the same message:

[image]
I'm using Node, Express and Typescript.
I have my folder `dist` and and also a `src` folder where start my project with my `index.ts`.

I tried differents ways with `vercel.json`, adding my `.ts` with and without slashes in the directory, but I didn't have luck. I followed this tutorial https://dev.to/tirthpatel/deploy-node-ts-express-typescript-on-vercel-284h 3 or 4 for more but always I receive the same message.

## My project structure

[image]

### vercel.json

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "dist/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node",
            "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "dist/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "lifeguards-analytics-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "watch": "tsc --watch & node --watch dist/index.js",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me find the problem because it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want any [routes](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#routes) configuration

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set your root directory to "backend" (the name of your folder). This setting can be configured in the vercel dashboard. Also to get more information try checking logs in your vercel dashboard.